# Get the size of a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Okay, so I have a 2D array z[50][50] and z's size is therefore 50 * 50, but if I say z.length I only get 50 back. How do I get the real size of a 2D array?

Comment: This question seems a bit vague: what does "real size" refer to?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In Java, 2D arrays are really arrays of arrays with possibly different lengths (there are no guarantees that in 2D arrays that the 2nd dimension arrays all be the same length)

You can get the length of any 2nd dimension array as `z[n].length` where `0 <= n < z.length`.

If you're treating your 2D array as a matrix, you can simply get `z.length` and `z[0].length`, but note that you might be making an assumption that for each array in the 2nd dimension that the length is the same (for some programs this might be a reasonable assumption).

Comment: note: this may violate some programming paradigms, but rules are made to be broken amirite?

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on what [Mark Elliot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4111400/3972558) said earlier, the easiest way to get the size of a 2D array given that each array in the array of arrays is of the same size is:

```
array.length * array[0].length
```

Comment: array[0].size() would mean it's not a 2D array but for example an array of Collections.