# Getting the array length of the second dimension

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I have a 2d array:

```
ProductAndCompanyHourArray[ProductLoopIndex][CompanyLoopIndex] = getCompanyHourTime;
```

I'm trying to loop though the 2d array per dimension so far I have:

```
ArrayLen(ProductAndCompanyHourArray) - ProductIndex
```

How would I loop though the second bit? (not working & get the length)

```
ArrayLen(ProductAndCompanyHourArray[ProductIndex]) ??
```

Comment: Olly, what is "not working" - do you get an error message? ArrayLen works fine on 2D arrays.

Comment: It's ok thanks, the solution is: ArrayLen(ProductAndCompanyHourArray[index])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the array length of the second dimension, you just use the [**ArrayLen**](http://cfdocs.org/arraylen) function:

```
<cfset DD = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9],[10]] />

<cfoutput><pre>
DD Length is #ArrayLen(DD)#

<cfloop index="i" from=1 to=#ArrayLen(DD)#>
    DD[#i#] Length is #ArrayLen(DD[i])#
</cfloop>

</pre></cfoutput>
```

That code works. If yours doesn't, provide the full relevant code and any error messages.

Answer (score 3):

In response to using Cold Fusion:

*About ColdFusion arrays
ColdFusion arrays differ from traditional arrays, because they are dynamic. For example, in a conventional array, array size is constant and symmetrical, whereas in a ColdFusion array, you can have rows of differing lengths based on the data that is added or removed.
A conventional 2D array is like a fixed-size table made up of individual cells.
A ColdFusion 2D array is actually a one-dimensional array that contains a series of additional 1D arrays. Each of the arrays that make up a row can expand and contract independently of any other column.*

I'll link to the answer of a similar question, should resolve your issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4111400/967977

The link states
**"You can get the length of any 2nd dimension array as z[n].length where 0 <= n < z.length."**

Comment: Can you briefly summarize the answer?